# Ubuntu hard drive partitions check

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, sony-vaio, ubuntu-13.04

I was given a brand new Sony Vaio Series Z (vpcz13v9e) by the company I'm consulting for.

I cannot use Windows for what I do, so I've asked the IT department of the company if they could set the latest Ubuntu version up on it - which they did (they mentioned some issues with UEFI and RAID though)

Thing is, I'm pretty sure they've left some parts of the disk drive out.

How can I easily check?

I basically need to:

- find out total disk drive situation
- check for unused parts
- format them
- add them to the total space I can now use.

EDIT #1 AFTER FIRST COMMENT

gparted starts and logs

```
/dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label

/dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label

/dev/sdd: unrecognised disk label
```

[image]

Plus Sony website specs for my laptop states:
**256GB Quad SSD (RAID 0)**

EDIT #2

Ok, I've now mounted the other 3 parts. How easy would it be to merge them all together so to have just one partition but bigger?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) is great for your situation.

1. Open terminal and install it with `sudo apt-get install gparted`.
2. Run it with `sudo gparted`.
3. After you have mounted all partitions, just right*click the partitions you want to remove and click `delete`. It will make the partition to be allocated space.
4. Right-click on the partition you want to extend, and click `Resize/Move`, and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: awesome. it was easier than i thought. i only now have to figure out how to deal with RAID. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [fdisk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk) to do this.

[image]